# Hibernate @Embedded in @Embeddable ignores annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to use an `@Embeddable` inside annother `@Embeddable`, which is supported according to the specs, however, it looks as though the JPA annotation in de `Code` class below is ignored. The enum is (de)serialized by ordinal instead of string representation. I can think of several workarounds, but that's not the issue. I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using hibernate 4.2.5 with Spring 3.2.4

```
@Entity
public class ExampleEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="example_embeddable",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="example_entity_id"))
    private Set<ExampleEmbeddable> embeddables = new HashSet<>();

    // This enum is (de)serialized as a string just fine
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AnotherEnum another;

    private String stuff;
}

@Embeddable
public class ExampleEmbeddable implements Serializable {

    @Embedded
    private Code code;

    // This enum is (de)serialized as a string just fine
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusEnum status;
}

@Embeddable
public class Code implements Serializable {

    public enum Version {
        RED,
        BLUE,
        GREEN
    }

    private String code;

    //Why is this enum is (de)serialized by ordinal?
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Version version;
}
```

Comment: It looks like there _was_ a Hibernate bug long ago, but it was fixed. Not sure why you were affected. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5937